# Reduce code and simplify the logic of IF-THEN-ELSE block

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm having a really hard time understanding how to best utilize if else statements.  For example:

```
$('.qty_input').keyup(function () {
var qtyValue = $('.qty_input').val();
    if (qtyValue >= number1 && qtyValue <= number10){
        if ($('option[value="2"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="2"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="3"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="3"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="4"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="4"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="1"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="1"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="2"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="2"]').wrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="3"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="3"]').wrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="4"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="4"]').wrap('<span/>')}
       }
       else if (qtyValue >= number2 && qtyValue <= number20){
        if ($('option[value="2"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="2"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="3"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="3"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="4"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="4"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="1"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="1"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="1"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="1"]').wrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="3"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="3"]').wrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="4"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="4"]').wrap('<span/>')}
       }
       else if (qtyValue >= number3 && qtyValue <= number30){
        if ($('option[value="2"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="2"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="3"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="3"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="4"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="4"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="1"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="1"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="2"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="2"]').wrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="1"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="1"]').wrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="4"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="4"]').wrap('<span/>')}
       }
       else if (qtyValue >= number4 && qtyValue <= 999999){
        if ($('option[value="2"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="2"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="3"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="3"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="4"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="4"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="1"]').parent("span").length) {$('option[value="1"]').unwrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="2"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="2"]').wrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="3"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="3"]').wrap('<span/>')}
        if ($('option[value="1"]').parent("span").length) {}else {$('option[value="1"]').wrap('<span/>')}
       }});
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can update this so it's cleaner and more effective? Thanks.

Comment: use switch instead of if

Comment: Does the order of the `if`s matter?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Shouldn't `option`s only ever have `<select>`, `<optgroup>` or a `<datalist>` parent, not a `span`?

Comment: I'm wondering why `unwrap` immediately followed by `wrap` on the same node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I noticed some patterns that can be converted into functions, or taken away at once.

```
$('.qty_input').keyup(function () {

    var qtyValue = $('.qty_input').val();
    // these 4 statements are executed no matter what. 
    // there is no point in duplicating them in each if-then block
    for(var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        if ($('option[value="'+i+'"]').parent("span").length) {
           $('option[value="'+i+'"]').unwrap('<span/>');
        }
    }


         // the pattern for the next part is simple
         // execute 4 statements of jQuery but exclude one part per each if-then block
         if (qtyValue >= number1 && qtyValue <= number10) { exclude(1); }
    else if (qtyValue >= number2 && qtyValue <= number20) { exclude(2); }     
    else if (qtyValue >= number3 && qtyValue <= number30) { exclude(3); }        
    else if (qtyValue >= number4 && qtyValue <= 999999)   { exclude(4); }        

    function exclude(num) {
        // loop from 1 to 4 to execute the same for each part
        // but only exclude the one statement that is passed 
        // into the function
        for(var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
            if(i!=num) {
                if (!$('option[value="'+i+'"]').parent("span").length) {
                     $('option[value="'+i+'"]').wrap('<span/>')
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create an object of the jQuery collections (for each `value=`). Because the unwrapping process is the same for every outer `qtyValue` condition, you can run that part of the code unconditionally, by iterating over the object's values and `unwrap`ping if the item's parent is a span. Then, make a function that takes as a parameter the `value` you want to ignore when `wrap`ping, and iterate over the values of the object that don't have that `value`.

It would also be nice if you could change your standalone `number#` variables into an array of ranges, for example

```
[
  [10, 20], // [number1, number10]
  [21, 30], // [number2, number20]
```

That'll not only be better for making your code concise when defining those ranges, but it'll also make it easier to `.find` the appropriate index to call `wrap` with - replace the four `if` / `else if` statements at the end with something like:

```
const indexToIgnore = 1 + ranges.findIndex(([min, max]) => qtyValue >= min && qtyValue <= max);
wrap(indexToIgnore);
```

In full:

```
$('.qty_input').keyup(function () {
  const qtyValue = $('.qty_input').val();
  const options = {
    1: $('option[value="1"]'),
    2: $('option[value="2"]'),
    3: $('option[value="3"]'),
    4: $('option[value="4"]'),
  };
  // unwrap all, code is the same regardless of `if` statement::
  Object.values(options).forEach((option) => {
    if (option.parent("span").length) {
      option.unwrap('<span/>')
    }
  });
  function wrap(keyToIgnore) {
    keyToIgnore = String(keyToIgnore); // object properties are strings
    Object.entries(options)
      .filter(([key]) => key !== keyToIgnore)
      .forEach(([, option]) => {
        if (!option.parent("span").length) {
          option.wrap('<span/>')
        }
      });
  }
  const indexToIgnore = 1 + ranges.findIndex(([min, max]) => qtyValue >= min && qtyValue <= max);
  wrap(indexToIgnore);
});
```

Comment: How are you excluding the one value per condition? I'm sorry I haven't dived into straight Javascript, I've only taken in jQuery.  I can sort of understand your function wrap(keyToIgnore). Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: jQuery *is* Javascript - jQuery is just a Javascript library, which runs on Javascript code and syntax, and is interacted with using Javascript code and syntax :)